# How to list a file starting with "2019_03" with extension ".text" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal, ls

I have many file in a linux system some like this:

```
2019_03_01.text
2019_03_01.jpg
2019_03_01.png
2019_03_02.text
2019_03_02.jpg
2019_03_02.png
...
.
2019_09_21.text
2019_09_21.jpg
2019_09_21.png
.
```

I want to list only starting "2019_03" with extension ".text " in python. I run the command on the linux terminal as follows:

```
ls /path/[2019_03]* | grep /*.text
```

How can i do this in python?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: You use the dupe - instead of "endswith" or the *.txt file patters you adapt your pattern to match your files...

Comment: actuallly i use glob and os modules but i couldn't do much to share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module will be your friend.

```py
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/2019_03*.text')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the regex library in python (re), and search for '.text'. To get the list of files, we can use the os module to list the files:

```
# ~ Libraries ~ #
import os
import re

# ~ Directory ~ #
path_to_directory = '/path/to/directory/'

# ~ List of files ~ #
file_list = os.listdir(path_to_dir)

# ~ Get only files with .text extensions ~ #
file_text = [x for x in file_list if re.search('.text',x)]
```